# How to reduce repetitive code in if/elif statement

Tags: python

What would be a better way to do the following pattern?

```
for platform_id in previous_platform_ids:
    if self.series.get(platform_id):
        del self.series[platform_id]
    elif self.seasons.get(platform_id):
        del self.seasons[platform_id]
    elif self.episodes.get(platform_id):
        del self.episodes[platform_id]
    elif self.movies.get(platform_id):
        del self.movies[platform_id]
    elif self.bundles.get(platform_id):
        del self.bundles[platform_id]
```

Basically, I want to iterate through a bunch of ids and remove that id from the list that contains it.

Comment: `.get` does not exist for list. Do you mean something like `try: del x[x.index(element)]; except ValueError: pass` ?

Comment: @jojonas they must be dictionaries, through context you can tell they must be dictionaries

Comment: do you only want to delete the id from the first list it is found in?

Comment: @JoranBeasley I highly doubt it. What if the same id is removed twice? Does it change the operation meaning?

Comment: I dont know, but with elif's it would only get rid of the first list (and op says this code works how he wants it to ... so) (although I suspect you are right that he wants to remove it from ALL lists with one call ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to iterate through each `content_type` and use the `getattr` method to check if it's there:

```
content_types = ['series', 'seasons', 'episodes', 'movies', 'bundles']
for url in previous_urls:
    for content_type in content_types:
        if getattr(self, content_type).get(url):
            del getattr(self, content_type)[url]
            break
```

Comment: I like this answer :)

Comment: The call to `getattr` is extraneous; you can iterate directly over `[self.series, self.seasons, self.episodes, self.movies, self.bundles]`.

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. assuming OP's original code was doing the right thing by only removing(at most) one item ... but yeah that would make it equivalent functionally

Answer (score 2):

```
self.series.pop(platform_id,None)
self.seasons.pop(platform_id,None)
self.episodes.pop(platform_id,None)
self.movies.pop(platform_id,None)
self.bundles.pop(platform_id,None)
```

seems like it would do the same thing (or actually not quite this will delete it from all dictionaries it(the key) is present in not just, the first one it finds, your code will only delete the first instance it finds ... not sure if that is intentional)

of coarse you could do something like

```
for content_type in content_types:
    getattr(self, content_type).pop(platform_id,None)
```

if you only wanted to delete the first one you found you could do

```
 content_dicts = [self.series,self.seasons,self.episodes,self.movies,self.bundles]
 next(x.pop(platform_id,None) for x in content_dicts if platform_id in x)
```

Comment: Am I missing something? Which data structure has this `.pop(..., ...)` method? I tried the list in Python 2 and Python 3.4, but `pop() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)`.

Comment: this is not the same as showing OP, You can delete 5 Elements, while only in the original code is deleted one at a time

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
dicts = [self.series, ..., ]
remove_id_func = lambda _id: map(lambda dct: dct.pop(_id, None), dicts)
```

Somehow keeping them in a list seems nicer, and now use it like this:

```
remove_id_func(some_id)
```

An even nicer thing is to keep them in a mapping:

```
dicts = {
    "series": self.series,
    "movies": self.movies,
    ...
}
```

And the remove function now becomes:

```
remove_id_func = lambda _id: map(lambda kv: kv[1].pop(_id, None), dicts.items())
```

You can use class methods with simple loops which is probably better than these one-liners which are unmaintainable.

Note that these operations remove the element from all lists, which is what you probably want.

Comment: I concure it is nicer to keep them in a list ... i think a dict is probably needless here (although you are right it is an improvement over the list) ... +1

Comment: A list comprehension `[dct.pop(_id, None) for dct in dicts]` instead of `map` would be nicer still.